# New information shifted my question - uncertain if it's proper to edit or newpost

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, etiquette

I've had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532705/mod-wsgi-with-python-venv-importerror-no-module-named-site) up for a few hours, and have been doing further research and experimentation on the problem at the same time. The new research (edited in at the bottom) seems like it might have refined the known information to the point that a better question-title would be "Setting PYTHONHOME breaks importing sites" or "mod_wsgi WSGIPythonHome directive not working" or something of that sort. I'm not sure if it would be better for my odds of getting an answer and/or for the site to edit the question to bring that to the forefront, or to post an entirely new question with a reference to the original. I can't scrap it entirely - the fact that I'm doing it with Apache mod_wsgi is a significant part of the reason why workarounds like "use a virtual environment" or don't work (can't activate it for the context that mod_wsgi runs the .wsgi file in). What's policy here?

Comment: If the question hasn't been answered, clarify away. The rule of thumb is do not invalidate answers.

Comment: but... avoid things like this: *"New data Sept. 16th:"* instead, just integrate the new information into the question as if it had always been there. We can use the edit history to see what has been added and when.

Comment: Thanks, made the changes and indicated fix.